# How can i pass the '-t azure://' target into a ruby inspec script?

Tags: ruby, azure, containers, inspec

If in my script I want to test azure resources using a ruby library (not inspec binary) running in a container:

```
def my_resource_groups
    rg = Inspec::Runner.new(conf={:vendor_cache=>'/app'})
    rg.add_target('/app/profiles/azure')
    rg.run
end

my_resource_groups()
```

with this `inspec.yml` definition

```
name: inspector
title: Azure InSpec Profile
maintainer: The Authors
copyright: The Authors
copyright_email: you@example.com
license: Apache-2.0
summary: An InSpec Compliance Profile For Azure
version: 0.1.0
inspec_version: '>= 2.2.7'
depends:
- name: inspec-azure
  url: https://github.com/inspec/inspec-azure/archive/master.tar.gz
```

And this test:

```
title "Azure Resource group spike"

control 'azure_resource_groups' do
  describe azure_resource_group do
    its('names') { should include 'my_resource_group1' }
  end
end
```

I get:

```
Skipping profile: 'inspector' on unsupported platform: 'debian/10.7'.
```

How do I pass the equivalent `-t azure://` argument to my ruby script, in the same way as I would if I did this:

```
sudo docker run \
-v /home/vagrant/scratch/share:/share \
-e AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="some_secret" \
-e AZURE_CLIENT_ID="some_client_id" \
-e AZURE_TENANT_ID="some_tenant_id" \
-e AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="some_subscription_id" \
chef/inspec \
exec /share/inspector \
-t azure:// \
--chef-license=accept
```

Answer (score 1):

just in case anyone else comes across this headache, pass the options as a map into the runner object when you instantiate it.  (note the vendor cache was tidied up as well)

```rb
def my_resource_groups
    rg = Inspec::Runner.new({:target=>'azure://',:vendor_cache=>'/app'})
    rg.add_target('/app/profiles/azure')
    rg.run
end

my_resource_groups()
```